# Minimizing large amount of variables

Tags: python

So, I am making a text based world generator as a hobby project and I am trying to find a way to minimize the amount of variables I have. Here is a snippet of code below for an example.

```
import time, random
class WorldGen(object):
    def generate():
        wo1 = random.randint(1, len(WO))-1
        #This list of variables continues to wo38
        print WO[wo1], #So on and so forth to WO[wo38]
        time.sleep(0.5)
        generate()
start = WorldGen()
start.generate()
```

Essentially, the question I am asking here is: How can I make the list of the 38 variables shorter in any way, such as a loop or something like that? If I don't provide enough info, please specify what you might need to know more about. Here is an example of output below.

```
# o o o ~ *  * ~
* o # ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
```

This is not how the whole of the output would look, but here is the key for the text making up the world. (That's what I mean by text symbols)

```
# = Tree
~ = Water
*  = Sand
o = Land
```

These text symbols representing parts of the word are put in a list like this.

```
WO = ["~", "*", "o", "#"]
```

Hope this is good enough explanation of text symbols.

Comment: What is stopping you from using a loop? Why do you use separate variables?

Comment: Well, with my basic knowledge of python, I didn't know any other way but to define all symbols in a line of the world as variables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whenever you have numbered variable names, think about using a list, tuple or dict instead:

```
def generate():
    wo = list()
    for i in range(38):
        wo.append(random.randint(1, len(WO))-1)            
        print WO[wo[i]],
```

If the order of the numbered variables matter, as they usually do, use a tuple or list. If the object is immutable, use a tuple. If the object needs to be mutated, use a list.

So, above, instead of having variables `wo1`, ..., `wo38`, you would have one list `wo`, with items `wo[0]`, ..., `wo[37]`.

A little tip: Make your variable names very distinct. Avoid variable names that differ only by capitalization, like `wo` and `WO`. The more similar the names, the easier it is to have a "senior moment" and type the wrong one. `data` and `date` always trips me up. Also, it's nice to write code that is easily understandable when vocalized -- maybe not important for you, but could be extremely important to some.

---

To generate a random world, you could use a list of lists to hold the "text symbols" (terrains):

```
import random

terrain = ["~", "*", "o", "#"]

def generate():
    """ Generate a random board represented by a list of lists """
    num_rows, num_cols = 3, 38
    board = [[random.choice(terrain) for col in range(num_cols)]
             for row in range(num_rows)]
    return board

def show(board):
    print('\n'.join([' '.join(row) for row in board]))

board = generate()
show(board)
```

prints things like

```
* * # ~ * o * o o * o * # ~ * ~ * * * * * o * o ~ * ~ o ~ * * * * o o # * #
o ~ ~ # ~ # * ~ # * ~ o # o ~ # ~ * # o ~ # ~ * o * # ~ ~ o # o o ~ ~ * o ~
o # # o * o ~ # * o ~ # ~ o ~ # * ~ ~ ~ # * o * # ~ ~ * o ~ ~ o * # * # # *
```

---

Above, the board was generated using nested [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
row = [random.choice(terrain) for col in range(num_cols)]
```

is equivalent to

```
row = list()
for col in range(num_cols):
    row.append(random.choice(terrain))
```

It's mainly just a shorter syntax.

---

Another little tip: I usually find it is better to separate print statements from calculations. The generation of the board is a calculation. The printing of the board should be done elsewhere. I used the `show` function to print the board, and `generate` to generate the board. This separation of duties will give you more flexibility when refactoring code and more control over when you want those actions to be performed.

---

To generate an infinite number of rows, I would use a [generator function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators):

```
import random
import time

terrain = ["~", "*", "o", "#"]

def generate():
    """ Generate a random board represented by a list of lists """
    num_cols = 38
    while True:
        yield [random.choice(terrain) for col in range(num_cols)]

def show(board):
    for row in generate():
        print(' '.join(row))
        time.sleep(0.5)

board = generate()
show(board)
```

A simpler way would have been to call `print` inside the while-loop:

```
while True:
    print(' '.join([random.choice(terrain) for col in range(num_cols)]))
```

but after extolling the virtue of separating calculation from printing, I feel obliged to show you the generator function solution.

Comment: This seems like a good idea, I am a programming noob, but I can see how it works. Good idea!

Comment: Although how would I add stuff like text symbols to the list?

Comment: You can append any object to the list: `wo.append('Hello there')`. (Err, is that what you mean by a "text symbol"?)

Comment: For example: # = A tree in the world. Or: o = Landmass in the world. This is what I meant by text symbols.

Comment: Also the tip on variables was helpful, the reason the variables were represented by wo and WO is because they were comprised of only 2 characters each, and to me, it looks more organized.

Comment: Ohh, I get what I was trying to ask about the list! (Facepalm)

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what you mean by "text symbol". But perhaps you are looking for a `dict`. If you make `wo` a dict, i.e. `wo = dict()`, then you can use strings `wo['tree'] = ...` or `wo['landmass'] = ...`, instead of `tree = ...` and `landmass = ...`.

Comment: To print multiple world symbols would I have to do this?                                                                      print WO[wo[i]], WO[wo[i]], #So on and so forth?

Comment: I will show what the output looks like and give a better explanation of what I mean.

Comment: Okay, I tried your method, but I am getting all the same characters on each line until it prints a new line. I am starting to think that I just need to define each variable and deal with it. Thanks for all the input and help though!

Comment: Now I understand what "text symbols" are. I've added some code suggesting how you could generate worlds.

Comment: Good, this seems like the kind of code that will help, thanks!

Comment: It works! How could I turn this into an infinite loop though? I want the world to generate forever. (I would use time.sleep to prevent stack overflow.)

Comment: When it generates infinitely, will each row be different?

Comment: Wow, thanks to you and your help with my hobby project, I was able to take off about 100 lines of code! This was extremely helpful and I actually learned a little bit in the process! Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: Now on to biome control and such!

Comment: Sorry if it feels like I am pestering for info, but how could you use console.set_color() to test if a certain symbol is printed so that symbol is the color of what it represents?

Comment: If you are talking about [this iOS module](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/docs/ios/console.html), then sorry I can't help you since I have no experience with it wouldn't be able to test anything I write. You'd be better off posting a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Source code for those who want it:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8
#Infinite world generator
#Thanks to unutbu for the concepts shown here.
import random, time, console

terrain = ["*", "#", "~", "~", "~", "o", "o", "o",
           "*", "~", "~", "~", "~", "o", "o", "o",
           "*", "~", "~", "~", "~", "o", "o", "o"]

def generate():
    num_cols = 30
    while True:
        yield [random.choice(terrain) for col in range(num_cols)]

def show(board):
    for row in generate():
        print "|", (' '.join(row)), "|"
        time.sleep(0.6)

def key():
    print "Key:"
    print "o = Landmass"
    print "# = Tree"
    print "* = Sand"
    print "~ = Water"

def menu():
    print "InfWorldGen v1.0.1"
    print "Type gen."
    start = raw_input("> ")
    if start == "gen":
        console.clear()
        key()
        print "[" + "=" * 61 + "]"
        board = generate()
        show(board)
menu()
```

Thanks to unutbu for most of the concepts here.

Answer (score 0):

@unutbu Here is an even shorter method of doing this, yet it still does the same thing:

```
import random, time

terrain = [
    "#", "o", "~", "*"
]

while True:
    world_tile = random.randint(1, len(terrain))-1
    print terrain[world_tile],
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: @unutbu Also, why would you have to do __range(num_cols)__, when you could just do __range(<number>)__?

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet an **even** shorter method.

```
import random
while True:
    print(' '.join([random.choice(['#','o','~','*'])),
```

It works seamlessly and is only three lines of code.